# can i remove the header value which i get from getallheaders() function :

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to remove the value of `getallheaders()` function:

I mantain the SSO login in my site so when I login my site, webgate maintain the values header so I get this value from header, but in logout I want it to remove the header. When it hit by SSO it takes some time to clear the header, I want to remove it manually by php code.

```
    $headerArray = array();
    $headerArray = getallheaders();
    foreach ($headerArray as $name => $value) {
        echo "<br>$name: $value\n";
    }
```

I get the header records from the above code.

Comment: @DhruvinSukhadiya, the [header] tag description itself says the tag is deprecated.

Comment: i am getting the values from getallheaders() i used header_remove(); for removing its value in logout but it didn't work for me

Comment: @Phil, [oops](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/45296)

Comment: Search all the files included and find where the `getallheaders()` is defined. Then copy it, modify it and define with different name, let say `getsomeheaders()` ; Now, call the new function where required. `$headerArray = getsomeheaders();`

Comment: $headerArray = getallheaders(); i used this and in logout want to clear the content from getallheaders(), my ques why we need to make another function with diff name like getsomeheaders();